# MongoDB: Does a $set result in an delete/insert of the document?

Tags: mongodb

I have a counter that I want to persist between requests on my web server and figured I could just stick it into a MongoDB database, because it already exists.

I am expecting an update to this counter about every 1-3 seconds.

However, I read that whenever you save a document in MongoDB the document gets deleted and re-inserted. And I am wondering if the same applies when you do a $set, without updating the entire document?

Also, if that is the case, would I expect any particular performance impact on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update that uses `$set` to modify one or more fields of an existing doc will only update the affected fields.  The update occurs in-place unless the changes cause the size of the document to increase beyond what's currently allocated for it.  When that happens the doc needs to be relocated; effectively deleting and re-creating the doc.

From [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-performance/#document-growth-and-the-mmapv1-storage-engine):

> For the MMAPv1 storage engine, if an update operation causes a
>   document to exceed the currently allocated record size, MongoDB
>   relocates the document on disk with enough contiguous space to hold
>   the document. Updates that require relocations take longer than
>   updates that do not, particularly if the collection has indexes. If a
>   collection has indexes, MongoDB must update all index entries. Thus,
>   for a collection with many indexes, the move will impact the write
>   throughput.